# Mapping normal distribution to a function

Tags: python, distribution

I am trying to map a function `4x²-sin(4x)` onto a random normal distribution curve and then with new data, generate the new function
[Red- Original Function, Blue- expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVAM8.png).

I have successfully generated the map of normal distribution using the code:

```py
x = np.linspace(0,1,200)

rng = np.random.default_rng()

xn = rng.normal(loc,scale, size)

yn = fct(x)              # fct is the function

ny = plt.hist(yn, 200, density=True, facecolor='r', alpha=0.75)
```

But I am not able to retrace it back to the function as needed (blue curve or similar).

Comment: What makes you think this is even possible?  The normal density has a completely different shape than your function.

Comment: Thank you for your query. Maybe I was not clear. The objective was to map the mean values of a given normal distribution onto the function.

Fortunately I found a way,
1) Plotting a normal distribution using random numbers
2) Generating the 'image' of the pdf in function (For every value of pdf compute function)
3) Just plotting.

I can share the code if it interests you, maybe I am still not clear!!!!